# How do I install graphviz 2.29 in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

In my ubuntu 12.04, the graphviz is not the latest version(2.29). I need some features available in the latest version of graphviz.
I tried to install the graphviz version 2.29, which requires libgraphviz4(>=2.18).
I anyhow installed libgraphviz4 and installed graphviz 2.29. For that I have to remove packages libcdt4 and libpathplan4.

Now whenever I try to generate graph, I get some problems:
For e.g.:

```
dot -Kfdp -n -Tpng -o samplePOS.png forcePOS.dot
```

It says:

```
dot: error while loading shared libraries: libgvc.so.6: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory

neato -Tps -o sample_1.ps sourcedot.gv
```

It says:

```
neato: error while loading shared libraries: libgvc.so.6: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So, I am looking for some ways so that I can run graphviz 2.29 in my ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First a warning for using PPA (mainly unstable)

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

The below PPA: **ppa:dperry/ppa-graphviz-test** is an ***unstable*** PPA. So, you are given warning.

Use this commands in a terminal to install the unstable 2.29 version of graphviz.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dperry/ppa-graphviz-test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove graphviz
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

If you get this error "graphviz : Depends: libgraphviz4 (>= 2.18) but it is not going to be installed", run the following

```
sudo apt-get remove libcdt4
sudo apt-get remove libpathplan4
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

Comment: I followed these steps But it is not able to install the latest graphviz version. I encountered the same problem which I have stated in the beginning, i.e. requires libgraphviz4(>=2.18)
http://imageshack.us/f/17/screenshotfrom201210041.png/

Comment: If you have previous installation of graphviz, remove it completely

Comment: Thank You very much. I could install graphviz 2.29 after removing packages libcdt4 and libpathplan4.

Comment: This installs `2.26.3` again for me. Any idea why?

Comment: I think it's because the latest build in PPA author's repo failed on `Precise Pangolin x64`, so if you're using 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 like me, watch out.

Comment: This method works for ubuntu 12.04 but I could not get it done for ubuntu 10.04

Comment: @bidur You asked question for 12.04.

Comment: @Olive my problem was solved for 12.04 . Just to let others know that this method may not work for 10.04

Comment: @bidur Are you on 32-bit 12.04, or 64-bit?

Comment: @KomodoDave My system is 12.04 (precise) 32-bit

Comment: The mentioned PPA doesn't seem to work anymore, but the one found at https://launchpad.net/~gviz-adm/+archive/ubuntu/graphviz-dev does. Gives the same error mentioned above, the suggested fix (remove libcdt4 libpathplan4) still fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 12.04 here.

What worked for me is:

1. Remove the following packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove libcdt4

   sudo apt-get remove libpathplan4
   ```
2. Install libgraphviz4

   http://www.graphviz.org/Download_linux_ubuntu.php
3. Install graphviz

   ```
   sudo apt-get install graphviz
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mess with some libraries i advice you to remove graphviz and install again

```
sudo apt-get remove graphviz
sudo apt-get remove graphviz-dev
sudo apt-get remove graphviz-doc
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

This is a same [situation](http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppMiscErrorLibgvcCannotOpenSharedObjectFile.htm) for other user

Comment: I tried this but this will install graphviz (2.26.3-10ubuntu1) NOT the latest version 2.29

Comment: But 2.29 still not stable. I advice you to stay at 2.26.3 as Ubuntu propose to avoid such conflicts

Comment: even I wish to stay with the stable version but I need some features provided by the version 2.29