# How to install pydot and graphviz?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, python3, pip

Im running a code that needs pydot and graphviz. I am using python 3.5 and ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64  bit.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/utils/vis_utils.py", line 17, in _check_pydot
    raise ImportError('Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot'
ImportError: Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot and graphviz for `pydotprint` to work.
```

I googled a little then found that I can install pydot with the code `pip install pydot`. But I know get this error. I am noob in ubuntu and I dont understand what to do. so how do I install pydot ?

```
deeplearning@deep-learning-virtual-machine:~$ pip install pydot
Collecting pydot
Collecting pyparsing>=2.1.4 (from pydot)
  Using cached pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pyparsing, pydot
  Found existing installation: pyparsing 2.0.3
    Uninstalling pyparsing-2.0.3:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 538, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/__pycache__/pyparsing.cpython-35.pyc' -> '/tmp/pip-45miiuxw-uninstall/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/__pycache__/pyparsing.cpython-35.pyc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 553, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/__pycache__/pyparsing.cpython-35.pyc'
```

Comment: `pip install pydot>=1.2.4` and `sudo apt-get install graphviz`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

python-pydot and graphviz are in the default Ubuntu repositories in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-pydot python-pydot-ng graphviz # python-pydot-ng isn't in the 14.04 repos
```

This [flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN4SH.png) was created with graphviz in Ubuntu. Because graphviz uses the built-in dot programming language which is included in the graphviz package, the source code of the linked flowchart is editable in any text editor even if python-pydot is not installed.

I don't know why you would want to install pydot with pip when you can get it from the Ubuntu repositories, but to answer your question I tried installing pydot anyway in a Python virtual environment with `pip3 install pydot` and it worked, so it is possible that you need to update pip to the latest version with `sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip`. I used `pip3` instead of `pip` because you wrote in your question that you are using Python 3.5.

Comment: wow thank you :) I have been following your comments as you updated it. It finally worked. Guess I need to google up more on ubuntu. pip, pip3, apt, apt-get... its all super confusing.

Comment: In Ubuntu many packages from PyPI are included in the default Ubuntu repositories and their package names are usually prefaced with `python-` and similarly for pip3 packages their package names in the Ubuntu repos are usually prefaced with `python3-`

Comment: Installing packages directly from PyPI with `pip` is the recommended approach: the latest version (Ubuntu repositories can be outdated), managed with a requirements file when appropriate, and installed to a `virtualenv`; *not* to the system's site-packages.

Answer (score 12):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37919183/4518341) on "Installing pydot and graphviz packages in Anaconda environment"

> I had the same issue and solved it by (order is **important**):
>
> 1. Installing `graphviz`, simply via `sudo apt-get install graphviz`
> 2. Installing `graphviz` for Python via conda `sudo ~/anaconda2/bin/conda install graphviz`
> 3. Finally, by installing `pydot` using conda `sudo ~/anaconda2/bin/conda install pydot`
>
> This answer is overdue but this post helped me (together with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438997/why-is-pydot-unable-to-find-graphvizs-executables-in-windows-8) that mentions the installation order), so hopefully this answer will help someone else. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7.
>
> P.S. apparently, there could be some issues with step 1 of the above algorithm, [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196230/how-do-i-install-graphviz-2-29-in-12-04) mentions how to fix them.

Comment: Please do not plagiarize. It's not against the site rules, but it's certainly not cool. Instead, you can copy-paste answers and attribute their source. I will edit your answer to demonstrate.

Comment: This is the right answer, though.

Answer (score 4):

Because you use python 3, the right command would be `pip3 install pydot graphviz`. You can install pip3 using `sudo apt install python3-pip`.

Comment: or simply `ln -s /path/to/pip3 /path/to/pip`

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 17.10, the ff fixed the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pydot graphviz
sudo pip3 install pydot_ng
```