# Get a logical diagram of a python code

Tags: command-line, python, diagram

I'm working on a big python script that is getting more and more complex.
I would like to generate a diagram (flow-chart?) of my code to have a better understanding of all the conditions and loops that are involved, even if the diagram doesn't understand the functions.
That way, I could also check that the logic is OK.

Here is an example to illustrate :
Let say I have this simple python script

```
a = 33
b = 200
name = "martin"

print("Starting script")
if b > a:
  print("b is greater than a")
  if name == "martin":
    print("The name is martin")
  else: 
    print("The name is not martin")
```

I could run a command in terminal like `diagram generate myScript.py` and it would output something like this :

[image: example of diagram]

Is there any package that could help me with that ?

Comment: surely you're better off with unit and acceptance tests? Anything more than a trivial program is going to create an enormous diagram that you're going to struggle to comprehend.

Comment: @RobertLongson I understand your point of view and I agree. The goal is exactly to review short-of trivial program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyFlowchart is a package to:

- write flowcharts in the Python language
- translate Python source codes into flowcharts

PyFlowchart produces flowcharts in flowchart.js flowchart DSL, a widely used flow chart textual representation. It's easy to convert these flowcharts text into an image via flowchart.js.org, francoislaberge/diagrams or some markdown editors.

To install PyFlowchart in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install pyflowchart
```

To make a flowchart for your example.py Python code run:

```
python3 -m pyflowchart example.py
```

PyFlowchart will output the generated flowchart.js DSL. Go to http://flowchart.js.org or use a markdown editor like Typora (`sudo snap install typora`) to turn the output code into a rendered logical diagram.

<sub>**Source:** revised from [pyflowchart - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyflowchart/)</sub>

Comment: Thank you 
I'm going to try that out

Comment: The command only display the flowchat right ? Cause I don't see any new file using it

Comment: flowchart DSL is a widely used flow chart textual representation. You need another app like Typora to turn the output code into a rendered logical diagram, or go to http://flowchart.js.org/.

Comment: Indeed. It worked like that ! Thank you

Comment: To automatically generate any kind of flowchart in Ubuntu using the dot programming language see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/917033/).